# Windows 7 Photo Import Tool

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

The Windows 7/Vista replacement for XPs Photo Import tool does not allow the same options when importing photos. Does anyone know of a port of the XP version for Windows 7, or perhaps how to copy the files for the program from a XP machine?

The options I am referring to that are different are the ability to: select a subset of photos to import (we use the cameras at multiple jobs before we import the photos), set the file names for the subset of photos, specify the folder the subset of photos will be imported into.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as we would like to move to Windows 7 from XP but this is a major hurdle for us.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [Windows Live Photo Gallery](http://download.live.com/photogallery) from [Windows Live Essentials](http://download.live.com/) and try that. The Import feature allows you to do the things that you say you want...